# How can I use "mv" to gather all the files found by "find" in the same folder?

Tags: command-line, find, mv

I can find all the files I want using `find` however I want to use `mv` to move them all to a certain folder. How can I do that?

Comment: This is a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388480/how-to-pipe-the-results-of-find-to-mv-in-linux

Comment: It's the top result on google for 'pipe find output to mv'

Comment: Not an answer, but a tip: often `find` is not necessary and Bash's `extglob` functionality can do what you want with less pain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A slight skew, `cp` and `mv` both support a `-t` target argument that lets you start with where your destination and end your command with a long list of things to copy or move. That lends itself perfectly to things like `find -exec ... {} +`, which will build a long command efficiently. Much more than `find -exec ... {} \;`

```
find . -type f -exec mv -t /new/path {} +
```

Comment: Okay. Now after looking into Linux SE as well, I found a very similar code and figured where I was making my mistake at. This answer is pretty solid.

Answer (score 0):

Classic approach - `find` + `while` loop

```
 find /your/top/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while IFS="" read -r -d "" FILENAME; do mv -t /path/to/destination/directory  "$FILENAME";done
```

Explanation:

- `find` gives you the list of files ( indicated by -type to ignore directories ) in `/your/top/directory` , descends at maximum 1 level in the directory structure, and prints the output as null-separated string;
- `while` loop in conjunction with `read` take each part of that null-separated string and store it to FILENAME variable.
- `mv` throws the current file to destination directory indicated with `-t` flag.

This approach is very useful when you want to avoid parsing `ls` output, and in fact, I've learned it [here](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html).